# Add days to a date

Tags: mysql

I have a table refering to past, current and future events, with a column "start_date" (YYYY-MM-DD) and a column "duration" (numeral value).

I want to make a query where ("start_date" + "duration") >= current_date (in order to extract data concerning only current events)

Is this possible? How? As you can guess I'm very new to MySQL

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take a look at [MySQL DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: If your column's data type is `DATE` (or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`) you can use the @Declan_K solution. If not, please provide more information about the data type and someone can help - though they may lecture you a bit for not using a `DATE` type :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(START_DATE,INTERVAL DURATION DAY) >=  CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[ADDDATE()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-adddate-function.php)** as well.

```
WHERE ADDDATE(START_DATE,INTERVAL DURATION DAY) >=  CURDATE()
```